# Only emit Gtk.Range value_changed signal when user stops dragging

Tags: linux, slider, range, vala

So I have a slider created with the following:

```cpp
var myscale = new Gtk.Scale.with_range(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 0.1);
```

I can listen for changes on the scale with:

```cpp
myscale.value_changed.connect(() => {
    message("%f".printf(myscale.get_value()));
});
```

But this prints out the value while the user is dragging, and I only want to know when the value has changed. I tried using the `state_changed` signal, but that seems to only emit when the user hovers, not when the user actually interacts with the widget.

Comment: There is also a `change_value` signal that has more parameters. I don't think there is an easy way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Some suggestions I've heard are to debounce it (only update the value after a timeout) or not listening to the event at all, and instead waiting for another event (like a button click or window close) to get the range value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GtkWidget "button-release-event" with "After" flag

Comment: Pretty short. Its a three year-old question. Would have been better to post code that illustrated your advice about arguments. Would have been *much* better to have included an explanation of what the questioner should have known or could have done to find the answer.